# Binding size '...' is larger than the maximum binding size (134217728)

Tags: compute-shader, webgpu

I want to handle large amount of data on GPU. I write simple test shader, that just make array ements negative. Here it is:

```c
@group(0) @binding(0) var<storage, read> sourceArray : array<f32>;
@group(0) @binding(1) var<storage, read_write> resultArray : array<f32>;

@compute @workgroup_size(256, 1)
fn main(@builtin(global_invocation_id) global_id : vec3<u32>) {
    resultArray[global_id.x] = -sourceArray[global_id.x];
}
```

And I want handle `100000000` elements. Here is JS code, that I wrote to do it:

```js
const ELEMENTS_COUNT = 100000000

// Source array
const sourceArray = new Float32Array(ELEMENTS_COUNT);
for (let i = 0; i < sourceArray.length; i++) {
    sourceArray[i] = i;
}

const gpuSourceArrayBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    mappedAtCreation: true,
    size: sourceArray.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE
});
const sourceArrayBuffer = gpuSourceArrayBuffer.getMappedRange();

new Float32Array(sourceArrayBuffer).set(sourceArray);
gpuSourceArrayBuffer.unmap();


// Result array
const resultArrayBufferSize = Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * (sourceArray.length);
const gpuResultArrayBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size: resultArrayBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC
});


// Compute shader code
const shaderModule = device.createShaderModule({
    code: shaderText
});

// Pipeline setup
const computePipeline = device.createComputePipeline({
    layout: "auto",
    compute: {
        module: shaderModule,
        entryPoint: "main"
    }
});

// Bind group
const bindGroup = device.createBindGroup({
    layout: computePipeline.getBindGroupLayout(0),
    entries: [
        {
            binding: 0,
            resource: {
                buffer: gpuSourceArrayBuffer
            }
        },
        {
            binding: 1,
            resource: {
                buffer: gpuResultArrayBuffer
            }
        }
    ]
});


// Commands submission
const commandEncoder = device.createCommandEncoder();
const passEncoder = commandEncoder.beginComputePass();
passEncoder.setPipeline(computePipeline);
passEncoder.setBindGroup(0, bindGroup);
passEncoder.dispatchWorkgroups(Math.ceil(ELEMENTS_COUNT / 256.0));
passEncoder.end();

// Get a GPU buffer for reading in an unmapped state.
const gpuReadBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size: resultArrayBufferSize,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST | GPUBufferUsage.MAP_READ
});

// Encode commands for copying buffer to buffer.
commandEncoder.copyBufferToBuffer(
    gpuResultArrayBuffer /* source buffer */,
    0 /* source offset */,
    gpuReadBuffer /* destination buffer */,
    0 /* destination offset */,
    resultArrayBufferSize /* size */
);

// Submit GPU commands.
const gpuCommands = commandEncoder.finish();
device.queue.submit([gpuCommands]);

// Read buffer.
await gpuReadBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.READ);
const arrayBuffer = gpuReadBuffer.getMappedRange();
console.log(new Float32Array(arrayBuffer));
```

And I receive an error `Binding size (400000000) is larger than the maximum binding size (134217728).` How can I fix this error? Maybe there is a way to create some continious data feed(stream) for GPU, to not provide all data as single piece?

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs because the size of the buffer you created exceeds the size of `maxBufferSize`.

Use [device.limits.maxBufferSize](https://gpuweb.github.io/gpuweb/#dom-supported-limits-maxbuffersize) to query the maximum buffer size that the current device can support.

The size of `maxBufferSize` is usually related to the memory size of the current device. Here are some numbers I tested with `wgpu`：

| Device | maxBufferSize |
| --- | --- |
| M1 max MacBook Pro (64G Memory) | **36864** MB = **36** GB |
| Intel MacBook Pro (2018, 32G Memorry) | **3072** MB = **3** GB |
| iPhone 6 Plus | **256** MB |
| iPad Mini 4 | **497** MB |
| iPhone 8 plus | **747** MB |
| iPad Pro 2018 | **947** MB |
| iPhone 12 Pro | **1433** MB |